# Allure-Pytest Failed Step marked as Pass

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, pytest, allure

I am using pytest for my selenium automation with Allure-pytest for report generation. I am following POM design pattern. My test step is marked with @allure.step in my page class and it has failed due to assertion error in my test method. When I generate the allure report, the test case is marked failed but the test step is marked as pass.

Sample test :

```
import allure



@allure.step("This is Step one")
def step_one():
    print("Reproducing the bug for Allure report")
    return True

@allure.testcase("This is test one")
@allure.description("This is to reproduce the allure step bug")
def test_one():
    assert step_one() == False
```

[image: allure-report screenshot]

command to run the test : pytest --alluredir allurereport
allure serve allurereport

I am using allure 2.9.0

metadata: {'Python': '3.8.8', 'Platform': 'Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0', 'Packages': {'pytest': '6.2.4', 'py': '1.10.0', 'pluggy': '0.13.1'}, 'Plugins': {'allure-pytest': '2.9.43', 'Faker': '8.10.2', 'pytest_check': '1.0.2', 'cov': '2.12.1', 'fixtures': '0.1.0', 'forked': '1.3.0', 'html': '3.1.1', 'metadata': '1.11.0', 'order': '1.0.0', 'reporter': '0.5.1', 'reporter-html1': '0.8.2', 'rerunfailures': '10.1', 'sugar': '0.9.4', 'xdist': '2.3.0'}}
plugins: allure-pytest-2.9.43, Faker-8.10.2, pytest_check-1.0.2, cov-2.12.1, fixtures-0.1.0, forked-1.3.0, html-3.1.1, metadata-1.11.0, order-1.0.0, reporter-0.5.1, reporter-html1-0.8.2, rerunfailures-10.1, sugar-0.9.4, xdist-2.3.0

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways I found which can mark the resulting step as failing in generated allure report

1. Instead of doing assert check in testcase, do the assert check in your step function like below

```py
@allure.step("This is Step one")
def step_one():
    print("Reproducing the bug for Allure report")
    assert True
    return True
```

2. Or to be more explicit, put your step logic inside a with clause like below. Note that with clause (running / capturing allure step here), will fail only for any specific exception. This is just an example to raise some random exception, you can also instead can have assert for expected condition.

```py
def step_one():

    with allure.step("This is Step one"):
        print("Reproducing the bug for Allure report")
        if not True:
            raise Exception("Step One Failed")
    
    # This now becomes optional!
    return True
```